# How to install ESP-IDF after installing PlatformIO?

Tags: toolchain, platformio, esp-idf

I installed PlatformIO to develop programs for the ESP32. PlatformIO automatically installs "everything" to create ESP-IDF projects.

In part that works but some things, like menuconfig, does not work in PlatformIO.

I also read here that some code does not compile in PlatformIO but it does compile with the Espressif development tools.

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/get-started/

I want to be able to install the Espressif tools but I am concerned that when I do this maybe some part from my PlatformIO installation will be overwritten, maybe with a different version, and then maybe I have more problems than I solve.

**Are there clear instructions how to install the ESP-IDF at the same time as PlatformIO and make sure they don't create problems with each other?**

Answer (score 2):

PlatformIO does download its dependencies in the user directory, e.g. windows:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\.platformio
```

whereas the espressif guide leads to globally installed python, compiler, etc.

Even if they are in different versions, PlatformIO does not set any environment variables and does not use anything else than what it downloaded itself.
Same goes the other way, the original esp-idf does not know anything about PlatformIO.

**tl;dr** You can use both independently of each other.

Comment: Thanks. After I installed the ESP-IDF I discovered that it's easy to use. It only needs a good editor. Now I use Visual Code, independent of PlatformIO, as editor. It works fine. It seems PlatformIO is currently not really suitable for ESP-IDF development.

Comment: according to ESP-IDF docs, Eclipse and VSC are the recommended IDE's. I tried both and now only working with Eclipse. https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/index.html#ide